# global variables scope for blog in jekyll

Tags: jekyll, blogs, liquid

instead of writing the layout for every blog post, i wish to declare the default layout for the posts index, and a different one for the single blog post. in my config i have

```
defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: "blog"
    values:
      layout: "posts"
```

and this works fine for the blog index (the one with the excerpts). but once i click on an article, i want to have a different layout so i tried:

```
defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: "blog"
    values:
      layout: "posts"
  -
    scope:
      path: "blog/_posts"
    values:
      layout: "blog-post"
```

but with no success. it still renders `layout: "posts"`

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path like "blog/_posts" will not match when setting defaults because "_posts" is a "magic folder".

But as your `index.html` is a `page`, you can use "scope type" and do :

```
defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: "blog"
      type: "pages"
    values:
      layout: "posts"
  -
    scope:
      path: "blog"
      type: "posts"
    values:
      layout: "blog-post"
```